# Testing views with rspec - undefined current_user in helper file when rendering view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, devise, view

I'm using rspec, with devise and trying to test my views. 
In a helper function which my view calls, I use the variable current_user
This works fine in practice, but using rspec, I get a sad 'undefinied variable or method current_user' error.

I've tried a lot of things that don't work.

```
@user = FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:user)
assign(current_user, @user)
sign_in :user, @user
def current_user
  @user
end
current_user = @user
view.stub!(:current_user).and_return @user
assign[:currrnet_user] = @user
```

Anyone know how to do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having the same trouble. Have you ever solved it? Let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this to get it to work.

```
RSpec.describe 'foos/index.html.erb', type: :view do                                                              
  before do                                                                     
    controller.singleton_class.class_eval do                                    
      def current_user                                                        
        User.find_by(username: 'schmoe')                                     
      end                                                                     
      helper_method :current_user                                             
    end                                                                         
    render                                                                      
  end

  ...                                                                           
end
```

Answer (score -3):

So, the solution to helper methods is to stub them. I don't really like this solution, because I see it as a bug, but it is the way to do what needs to be done.

Comment: So, you need to show us *how* you stubbed this. I need to accomplish the same thing, but you did not show the answer. Please show how/where you stubbed this for the view to pick it up.